# Record Level Translation in sfdc

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-apps, salesforcedx-cli, translation, translation-workbench

I came across a requirement in which users should be able to input the record data in salesforce using thier native language and should be able to view in thier native language. I know this is not possible from salesforce OOTB translation.

Is there any third party tool? any app exchange applications or any workaround for this?

The challange here seems to be the insertion and updation of records. I mean if a spanish user provides inputs in spanish, then how do we save those data, how the validations will work? how those data would be retrived by any other user in thier native language.

Can anyone suggest me something related to this??

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The form labels can be localized, text can be entered in native language, picklists can be translated, numbers and dates are formatted for the user locale. The thing Salesforce doesn't support is multi-lingual records where different users can enter language specific variants of the (typically textual) data in the same fields. So you can't really have a single record that represents the same data in different languages without using different fields to store those values.

Answer (score 1):

In classic there are standard "local name" fields on contact and account. They are not much more than a custom field, but they have some minor features in how they surface in searches.  This minor search functionality doesn't carry to lightning, so they basically are just like custom fields.

We do have some objects where we use two fields for some key data points, one for "native language" field and one for corporate language.  That is the only option, else you would have multiple records for a given record which could be problematic.

Knowledge articles are the only part of Salesforce that offer native translation for the data, as far as I can recall.